# Add coulmn with StructField types to the dataframe in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, schema

I have an input data as below-

```
Customer_ID,General,General

Channel,Nominal,Character

WeekDateSunday,Discrete,Numeric

RevenueWeekN01,Continuous,Numeric

RevenueWeekN02,Continuous,Numeric

RevenueWeekN03,Continuous,Numeric

RevenueWeekN04,Continuous,Numeric

RevenueWeekN05,Continuous,Numeric

RevenueWeekN06,Continuous,Numeric

RevenueWeekN07,Continuous,Numeric

RevenueWeekN08,Continuous,Numeric
```

I need output data as below, just with adding one column(This column is structField based on the column 3):

```
Customer_ID,General,General, StructFieldType 

Channel,Nominal,Character, StructField(Channel,StringType(), True) 

WeekDateSunday,Discrete,Numeric, StructField(WeekDateSunday,DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN01,Continuous,Numeric, StructField(RevenueWeekN01,DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN02,Continuous,Numeric, StructField(RevenueWeekN02,DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN03,Continuous,Numeric, StructField(RevenueWeekN03,DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN04,Continuous,Numeric, StructField(RevenueWeekN04,DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN05,Continuous,Numeric, StructField(RevenueWeekN05,DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN06,Continuous,Numeric, StructField(RevenueWeekN06,DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN07,Continuous,Numeric StructField(RevenueWeekN06,DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN08,Continuous,Numeric StructField(RevenueWeekN06,DoubleType(), True)
```

Following is the code that I have used, is it correct?

```
data_type.withColumn('structformat',when(col("Description") == 'Numeric', StructField(col("Field_Name"),DoubleType(), True)).otherwise(StructField(col("Field_Name"),StringType(), True)).show()
```

It is throwing below error when executing-

```
AssertionError: field name should be string
```

Comment: I suppose what you have written is correct please do elaborate your question and make it specific.

Comment: When I execute the above code, it is throwing below, Something I should include in the withColumn method.
AssertionError: field name should be string @Sundeep

Answer (score -1):

Probably the error is where you are having single quotes just change it to double quotes and you could get rid of the error

```
data_type.withColumn("structformat",when(col("Description") == "Numeric", StructField(col("Field_Name"),DoubleType(), True)).otherwise(StructField(col("Field_Name"),StringType(), True)).show()
```

Still getting any issue do comment else please approve the answer if helpful.

Edit:

```
Customer_ID,General,General, StructFieldType 

Channel,Nominal,Character, StructField("Channel",StringType(), True) 

WeekDateSunday,Discrete,Numeric, StructField("WeekDateSunday",DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN01,Continuous,Numeric, StructField("RevenueWeekN01",DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN02,Continuous,Numeric, StructField("RevenueWeekN02",DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN03,Continuous,Numeric, StructField("RevenueWeekN03",DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN04,Continuous,Numeric, StructField("RevenueWeekN04",DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN05,Continuous,Numeric, StructField("RevenueWeekN05",DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN06,Continuous,Numeric, StructField("RevenueWeekN06",DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN07,Continuous,Numeric StructField("RevenueWeekN06",DoubleType(), True) 

RevenueWeekN08,Continuous,Numeric StructField("RevenueWeekN06",DoubleType(), True)
```

Try this once

Comment: Still getting the same error, is it possible to add StructFiled in column?

Comment: Try the added new piece of code, i suppose it should be expecting string as a paramenter

Comment: @Sundeep, it has nothing to do with single quote.

Comment: @prazy as far as i see the entire code just works, what could be the problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by above code is working ? Can you show me your DataFrame?

Comment: In the when and otherwise condition, there is this line, `StructField(col("Field_Name", DoubleType(), True)` which evaluates to `StructField(Column<Field_Name>, DoubleType(), True)` which is wrong. The first parameter should be of `string` type, not a `column` type. It should be something like, `StructField('string',...)`. Also, the expected output and the related code won't give you the result because of that conflict.